# Prompting a macro on close of workbook, but kill the closing if user press "No"

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am trying to execute a macro on close of a workbook.

The macro works perfectly but the problem is the closing function. I want a user to be prompted to say "Yes" or "No" when closing the workbook. If the user presses "Yes" the workbook should save as xlsm and be closed.

If the user presses "No" the macro should be executed so that the user is sent to sheet "Projektinformation" and the workbook should not be closed.

Here is my code, any thoughts?

```
Sub Auto_Close()
Dim OutPut As Integer
OutPut = MsgBox("Projektinformation ifylld?", vbYesNo, "Projektinformation.")
If OutPut = 6 Then
'Output = 6(Yes)
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
Else
'Output = 7(No)
Sheets("Projektinformation").Select
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Try using `If OutPut = vbYes Then`.  ...but what's not working here? Is there an error, or is nothing happening? What's the question?

Comment: Are you calling this function from the Workbook_BeforeClose event?

Comment: Hi i am calling the function from the workbook close event.

THe issue is that it even if you press "No" it just close the workbook, instead of not closing it and go to the sheet "Projektinformation".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are putting the code in the wrong place. It should be in the [Workbook.BeforeClose Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194765.aspx) event macro in the **ThisWorkbook** code sheet.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim OutPut As Integer
    OutPut = MsgBox("Projektinformation ifylld?", vbYesNo, "Projektinformation.")
        If OutPut = 6 Then
        'Output = 6(Yes)
        ThisWorkbook.SaveAs FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
    Else
        'Output = 7(No)
        Cancel = True
        Sheets("Projektinformation").Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Note the `Cancel = True`. This tells Excel to halt the close operation and continue processing instructions.

Answer (score 4):

From your comment, I'm inferring that your code looks something like this on the `Workbook_BeforeClose` side:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel as Boolean)
    Call Auto_Close()
End Sub
```

The problem is the code does exactly what you asked it to!  It runs your Auto_Close subroutine (before the workbook closes) and then proceeds to close the workbook!

In order to achieve what you are trying to achieve, you have to change the `Cancel` parameter, passed into the Workbook_BeforeClose sub, to `True`.  When `Cancel = True` the workbook will cancel the close event, otherwise it will continue as usual.  I would either pass `Cancel` into your sub by reference and change the flag depending on what your user clicks or make `Auto_Close()` a function that returns a boolean, indicating whether or not to continue closing the workbook.

**EXAMPLE**

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel as Boolean)
    If SomeCondition = True Then
        Cancel = True  '<-- Workbook will stay open
    Else
        Cancel = False  '<-- Workbook will close as usual
    End If
End Sub
```